# Update table via join without key relation

Tags: sql-server, join, sql-update, row-number

What I have:

Two tables A and B.

```
A: Col1 Col2 Col3 Col1_Transformed Col2_Transformed

B: Col1 Col2 Col3
```

They have exact the same columns except some modified data, neither of them have primary key, unique field or whatever (it's extreme case that I need to handle).

Table A contains only part of data from table B. 
Lets say, I read table B in batches for 10000 rows, then I modify data and write it in to table A (*_Transform columns).

What I need:

I need to update table B using data from table A.
It will be easy having primary key or some identity column:

```
UPDATE target
SET  target.Col1 = source.__Col1
FROM B target
join A as source 
ON  target.Id = source.Id
```

But I don't have any.

Next natural guess is to relay on natural key, formed out of Col1 Col2 Col3.

```
UPDATE target
SET  target.Col1 = source.__Col1
FROM B target
join A as source 
ON  target.Col1 = source.Col1  AND 
    target.Col2 = source.Col2  AND 
    target.Col3 = source.Col3
```

This thing will not work, the reason is in possible NULL value comparation. If target.Col1 or source.Col1 is NULL, than whole record is omitted from update.

Guess #3 (using row number):

I would like to add row_number to table A, it will be my key.

A: row_numb Col1 Col2 Col3 Col1_Transformed Col2_Transformed

And than just join table B:

```
UPDATE target
SET  target.Col1 = source.__Col1
FROM B target
join A as source 
ON  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY target.Col1,target.Col2,target.Col3) = source.ROW_NUMB
```

Bur row_nubmer cannot be used in join clause.

Any ideas how to do it?

Comment: Your question is not clear. It seems you want to add an incrementing integer to table B? Can you just add a new column and set the identity property to true?

Comment: You can use Coalesce in #2 option or use common table expression and Row_number for #3

Comment: @sean-lange, I cannot modify table B. No changes to existing schema, table A is just temporary table #A.

Comment: @sqlhdv, though about Coalesce. Dont know how to do it with CTE in 3rd case, can you show an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you want `NULL` to match for the joins, you could do that :

```
UPDATE target
SET  target.Col1 = source.__Col1
FROM B target
join A as source 
ON  (target.Col1 = source.Col1 OR (target.Col1 IS NULL AND source.Col1 IS NULL)) AND -- most reliable way to do it
    ISNULL(target.Col2,'-1') = ISNULL(source.Col2,'-1')  AND -- less reliable but more concise, replace -1 by any data that cannot be in the tables
     (target.Col3 = source.Col3 OR (target.Col3 IS NULL AND source.Col3 IS NULL))
```

Comment: Yeah, I thought about ISNULL and COALESCE. Looks like I will stop on most reliable one. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Modification of your query with `ISNULL`

```
UPDATE target
SET  target.Col1 = source.__Col1
FROM B target
join A as source 
ON  IsNull(target.Col1,'') = IsNUll(source.Col1,'')  
    AND IsNull(target.Col2,'') = IsNull(source.Col2,'')  
    AND IsNull(target.Col3,'') = IsNull(source.Col3,'')
```

`CTE` example:

```
;With CTETableA 
AS
(
Select Col1,Col2,Col3,Col1_Transformed,Col2_Transformed
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Col1,Col2,Col3) id
       from A
),
CTETableB
As
(
Select Col1,Col2,Col3,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Col1,Col2,Col3) id
       from B
)

UPDATE target
SET  target.Col1 = source.Col1
FROM CTETableB target
join CTETableA as source 
ON  target.Id = source.Id  

Insert into B(Col1)
Select Col1 from CTETableB
```